# Magento Weird query 100% SQL cpu spike

Tags: mysql, magento

Currently have an issue with following query spawning multiple times:

```
SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_a...
```

Whatever it is, it's causing my CPU to spike to the roof...

My ony solution so far is to reboot the server entirely...

Hope somebody solved tis alreay...
Running Magento 1.9.x with Varnish 4.0 and Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move away from Magento 1.9 it's time to move...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error previously on Magento 1.9 and found that running:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

from a shell prompt fixed the issue.
The root cause seems to related the the core URL rewrite funcionality.